# Date from String using DateFormatter returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdate

I've a String like `yyyy-MM-dd` and I want create a `Date` with this.

```
static func dateFromStringWithBarra(date : String) -> String {
    print("DATE: \(date)")
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let date_from_format = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
    print("date_from_format: \(date_from_format)")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    print("date_from_format: \(date_from_format)")
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date_from_format!) // <- nil
}
```

OUTPUT:

`DATE: 2018-11-04
date_from_format: nil
date_from_format: nil`

Comment: Works fine for me on the Swift playgrounds. (Xcode 10, Swift 4.2)

Comment: works fine for me as well in playgrounds.

Comment: What I can do??

Comment: Are you sure there is no whitespace in your `date` string?

Comment: No, this is correct. But I solve using `dateFormatter.isLenient = true`. I don't know why, but is works.

Comment: if `isLenient` worked that means you have a problem with your date string. `isLenient  = true` means something like guessing a possible true value from given string. Eg. 2018/02/29. there is no 29 Feb so when `isLenient  = true` it will become March 1. with `isLenient  = false` it will be nil

Comment: @Augusto: What is your timezone? `print(TimeZone.current.identifier)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, mine was solved by some reason just by adding the locale to the DateFormatter:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_MX_POSIX")
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

A few things about that code:

1) Not sure why you use two different date formats
2) You should avoid if possible to use force unwrapping, in this case probably guard would be a good choice.

Meaning that the code should look more like this:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

guard let date_from_format = dateFormatter.date(from: date) else {
    return ""
}
return dateFormatter.string(from: date_from_format)
```

Comment: The point of two formats is to convert a date string to a new date string in a different format. Your code just returns the same string so there's no point to it. And your answer doesn't explain the issue.